# find the top left first first visible element in wiew port using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying an ebook in a webpage and would like to be able to create a bookmark inside the document. For this A would like to find the first visible element in the viewport and use it as bookmark. What is the way to achieve this using jquery or plain javascript?

Comment: Take a look at this [Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)

Comment: seems to be exactly what I need. Do you know what happens if an element is only partially visible in the viewport?

Comment: you should write this an an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin [Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport). It might be exactly what you want.